# Appium_lib with Xcode 6 page elements mssing

Tags: ios, ruby, automation, appium, pry

I just started iOS Automation with Appium v1.3.5 by following the setup and sample app test tutorial that appium provides here - http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/ios.html?java#starting-the-console.

Using Pry on the Appium Ruby Console page command to filter out elements I noticed that elements that were not on screen, meaning those  that i had to scroll down to were not being shown. The tutorial says that page class :UIAStaticText will bring back all the mentioned elements on the page but instead i get a nil for those elements not on my current screen. The scroll command has also failed me. But why scroll if i just want to return elements on the page. How can i accomplish this? Is it my simulator (iphone 6 iOS v8.1)? Is it Xcode? I know Xcode 6 has issues with appium. please help. Thanks!

```
  name, label, value: AAPLSliderViewController
  UIAStaticText
  name, label, value: Steppers
  nil
  [2] pry(main)>
```

I am also missing the network traffic information.

```
  {
   :script => "UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().windows()[0].getTree()"
   } 
   post /execute
   {
  :script => "UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().windows()[1].getTree()"
   }
    post /execute
   {
   :script => "mobile: getStrings"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page will only show those elements that the user can see. OR those that are on screen . If you have to scroll to see a cell, static text element etc.. it won't be available through page.

The following worked for me:

```
   b = $driver.find_element :name, 'Sign In' 
   $driver.execute_script 'mobile: tap', :element => b.ref
```

However, I wouldn't recommend the above method if you're working with hybrid apps. I would suggest to switch to webview like this: set_context(available_contexts[1]). This will allow you to use css which doesn't need SWIPE or SCROLL To!! Only possible outside your "NATIVE_APP" though.